# Groupy with collect_list with condition inside is not working

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I try to `groupby` rows and `aggregate` using `collect_list` in order to get dictionary, but without `nulls`. I also do not want to use `to_json` function.

When I execute below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct, col

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", None, "c"),
    ("a", "b", "c"),
    ("b", None, "c"),
], ["id", "code", "name"])

dff = df \
      .groupby("id") \
      .agg(collect_list(struct(*[column for column in df.columns if col(column).isNotNull()])))

display(dff)
```

I do not know why I get below error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I tried also this:

```
dff = df \
      .groupby("id") \
      .agg(collect_list(struct(*[when(df[column].isNotNull(), col(column)) for column in df.columns])))
```

but then I get not proper results:

[image]